# Prove triangle ABC is equilateral triangle given that $2\sin A+3\sin B+4\sin C = 5\cos\frac{A}{2} + 3\cos\frac{B}{2} + \cos\frac{C}{2}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Let the triangle ABC have angles such that:

$2\sin A+3\sin B+4\sin C = 5\cos\frac{A}{2} + 3\cos\frac{B}{2} + \cos\frac{C}{2}$

Prove triangle ABC is equilateral triangle.

Comment: I do not know how to start, I have never had a problem like this.

Comment: First, can you prove that it is possible for ABC to be equilateral? (This is easier than proving it HAS to be equilateral)

Comment: What is origin of the problem? Maybe you might include that information into the post. After all, it is general advice to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your advice ... I will try to solve this problem ...This problem is a part of my advanced school exam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$10\cos\dfrac{A}{2} + 6\cos\dfrac{B}{2} + 2\cos\dfrac{C}{2} = 10\sin \left(\dfrac{B+C}{2} \right) + 6\sin\left(\dfrac{A+C}{2}\right) + 2\sin \left(\dfrac{A+B}{2}\right)$

$\ge  10\sin\left(\dfrac{B+C}{2}\right) \cos\left( \dfrac{B-C}{2}\right) + 6\sin\left(\dfrac{A+C}{2} \right)\cos \left(\dfrac{A-C}{2}\right)+ 2\sin\left(\dfrac{A+B}{2}\right) \cos \left(\dfrac{A-B}{2}\right)$

$=5 (\sin B+\sin C)+3 (\sin A+\sin C)+ (\sin A+\sin B) = 4 \sin A + 6 \sin B+ 8 \sin C$

Thus we have $5\cos\dfrac{A}{2} + 3\cos\dfrac{B}{2} + \cos\dfrac{C}{2} \ge 2 \sin A + 3 \sin B+ 4 \sin C$

Its clear that equality occurs when $A=B=C = 60^{\circ}$

Comment: Why "$\le$" ? ... I think -1 $\le$ cos $\le$ 1...so it is "$\ge$" ...

Comment: Corrected that :)

Comment: Your computation is the clue to the proof, but the logic of the argument is not yet complete. You should have said: Thus we have $5\sin B \ldots \geq\ldots 4\sin C$ **with equality iff** $\cos{B-C\over2}=\cos{A-C\over2}=\cos{A-B\over2}=1$.